# How to debug 'init()' process in Httpmodule?

Tags: debugging, httpmodule, init

How to debug HttpModule (ASP.NET C#) in Windows 7 with IIS 7.0. If I want to attach aspnetworkerprocess in HttpModule using VS2010, I am not able to see aspnetworkerprocess.

Please let me know how to debug `httpmodule` on Windows Vista with IIS7.0 using Visual Studio 2010.